# Breezejs without server metadata

Tags: breeze

Playing with breezejs. Here is a code:

```
var dataService = new breeze.DataService({
                    serviceName: "/api/articles",
                    hasServerMetadata: false
                });
                var ms = new breeze.MetadataStore();

                var manager = new breeze.EntityManager({
                    dataService: dataService,
                    metadataStore: ms
                });

                var query = new breeze.EntityQuery().from("Query");

                manager.executeQuery(query).then(function (data) {
                    // this fails
                    var articles = manager.executeQueryLocally(query);
                    console.log(articles);
                }).fail(function(e) {
                    alert(e);
                });
```

Without line **var articles = manager.executeQueryLocally(query);** everything is ok. With it it says "entityType is null". I suppose that I need to add entity type but not sure how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of v 0.81.2, there is now a sample using breeze without server metadata, running against an in-memory server side datastore.  The sample is called ToDo-NoEF and is available via download from the breeze site.

Answer (score 1):

EntityType information can be added to the metadataStore via the AddEntityType method.  The metadataStore is most easily accessed via the EntityManager's metadataStore property.

We will also be adding a sample using breeze without server metadata within the next week or so.  But for now...

Here is a simple example of adding Entity types to the metadataStore. This is only a partial example because other related types would need to be added as well to complete it.

```
        var et = new EntityType({
            shortName: "Person",
            namespace: "Sample_WebApi.Models"
        });
        et.addProperty( new DataProperty({
            name: "personId",
            dataType: DataType.Int32,
            isNullable: false,
            isPartOfKey: true,
        }));
        et.addProperty(new DataProperty({
            name: "firstName",
            dataType: DataType.String,
            isNullable: false,
        }));
        et.addProperty(new DataProperty({
            name: "lastName",
            dataType: DataType.String,
            isNullable: false,
        }));
        et.addProperty(new DataProperty({
            name: "birthDate",
            dataType: DataType.DateTime,
            isNullable: true
        }));
        et.addProperty(new NavigationProperty({
            name: "meals",
            entityTypeName: "Meal",
            isScalar: false,
            associationName: "personMeals"
        }));
        metadataStore.addEntityType(et);
```

Comment: I tested this but no success. I will wait your example you mentioned there. Thanks.